# Scala Spark how to use --files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a minimal app with something like

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1g --class myClass --files $HOME/password,$HOME/user myJar
```

if inside my app I do:

```
println(SparkFiles.get("password"))
```

I do retrieve some kind of path that looks like:

```
hdfs/uuid/106046e5-67a2-4655-bc5b-1652ff9854f9/yarn/data/usercache/someuser/appcache/application_1517185426006_1181601/spark-fc9624fa-7561-4e8f-bcf8-15e2c3328f67/userFiles-19f71d74-0fd0-4324-8b1a-e5a8e075de06/password
```

But how to use the content of that file inside my app? I did try:

```
sc.textFile(SparkFiles.get("password"))
```

But somehow I have an error "input path does not exist". All I want to do is use the content of those simple text files in cluster mode.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably here:

```
--deploy-mode cluster
```

`SparkFiles` are managed by the driver and in the cluster mode driver is started on an arbitrary chosen node. So the path should be defined for this node, not the one on which you call `spark-submit`.

Since don't know which one is it, path has to be valid for each node (`https` URL is one choice, DFS another). Since you call `sc.textFile` it would make more sense to just put this file on HDFS and move on. `SparkFiles` are useful mostly for files, which will be accessed locally, by libraries which cannot easily communicate with HDFS.